# How is possible to apply some logic to this documentation about concatenation of variables in alphabetical order?

Tags: php, variables, text, concatenation, payment

The documentation below explains on how to generate a MAC code in PHP for a message authentication:

https://docs.evosnap.com/hosted-payments-section/message-authentication-code-mac/

It says, you need to concatenate the variables in alphabetical order, for example:

```
// parameters and values
$code = “merchant”;
$action = “get_order”;
$return = “json”;
$merchant_order_id = “808”;

// concatenate the parameter values in alphabetical order by parameter name
$plain = $action.$code.$merchant_order_id.$return;
```

As you can see in the above example the variables are in alphabetical order in PHP, but I never heard about you can know the names of the variables in execution time, how can this API check if the variables will concatenated in alphabetical order? I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Well unless you're using [variable varaible](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) names, its basically just saying "the api expects the parameters in this specific order" which happen to be an alphabetical order. I feel this is actually quite clever to make sure developers implement a string requirement in a very specific way (havinng an SDK would be an alternative).

---

Otherwise, you can use an array of keys and [key sort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) them...

```
// parameters and values
$array = array(
  'code' => 'merchant',
  'action' => 'get_order',
  'return' => 'json',
  'merchant_order_id' => 808       
);

// Sort the array by key
ksort( $array );

// concatenate the parameter values in alphabetical order by parameter name
$plain = implode( '', $array );
```

---

**Update 2018/02/20**

Their code is building a "signature" by concatenating a string in a specific order

```
// concatenate the parameter values in alphabetical order by parameter name
$plain = $action.$code.$merchant_order_id.$return;
// then add the private authkey
$plain.= $authkey;
// now generate the signature using the md5() function
$signature = md5($plain);
```

The `$signature` will be a 32 character string from the MD5 function

If you changed the order of the variables use to build `$plain`, you would receive a different signature from the `md5()` function.

The API will take the finite number of parameters that you provide it, and in the exact same order, perform the same MD5 function to ensure the request has not been modified.

There are no "smarts" here, simple string concatenation, All they are wanting is that the developer performs the MD5 function in the exact same order that they will perform it from their side.

Comment: Your explanations doesn't answer  my question, is a very well approach but not the answer. You're ignoring they aren't using variable variable names, in the example I exposed you only look normal variables sortered alphabetically in a manual way. They have `$a, $c, $z, $q` and they implode `$a.$c.$q.$z`, but how php or the API will check if that concatenation is in alphabetical order. HARD to understand for me. Can you explain better?

Comment: @CrishkCorporation I have appended to my Answer